# Passing struct between code generated by different compilers

Tags: c, struct

The memory layout of a struct is up to the compiler. So what happens when some code compiled by one compiler uses a struct generated by code compiled by another compiler?

For example, say I have a header file that declares a struct `somestruct`, and a function that returns the struct. One source file defines that function and is compiled by compiler `A`. Another source file uses than function and is compiled by compiler `B` and links against the binary of the other source file.

If the two compilers create two different layouts for `somestruct`, then what's the layout of the variable returned by the function? Does it defer to one compiler's layout, or will there be a memory bug when the second source file tries to access elements of the struct returned by the first source file? Is it an error at compile time or link time?

Comment: If the two compilers generate different layouts, that will likely lead to memory corruption. In general, however, compilers for the same platform (i. e. CPU and OS) tend to conform to some sort of ABI, so this is generally not a problem (beware of Microsoft's compilers, though – they have a tendency of not respecting platform ABIs… but who in their right mind would use Microsoft's toolchain anyway when there are alternatives?)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I think you got that backwards. Windows is the platform, and Microsoft defines the platform, and hence the ABI. When other compilers deviate, it's their own damn problem, because *they* won't be able to call system libraries and many third party libraries.

Comment: @delnan Oh dear. That's nice and all in theory, but where there are compilers ages older than MSVC & co., and Microsoft goes straight against well-established de-facto standards… yeah, you can say it's their right, but is it a nice thing to do? hardly.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant It wasn't nice 22 years ago, when MSVC came out (I assume that's also when the ABI split happened). Nowadays it's a neutral fact that MSVC's ABI is the standard. *Wishing it wasn't* is "nice in theory". I'd rather get things done, and luckily I'm not constrained to MSVC in that endeavor.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant a bit OT for this thread, but one benefit to using MS's toolchain is that you can distribute nice small binaries. If you use, say, mingw-w64 + wx, then you have to lumber a 25MB base DLL along with all your executables, plus other large DLLs. (Or statically link which does not save much, if anything). And distributing your own built DLLs risks leading to DLL-hell.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function will return a structure as specified by the ABI of the compiler of the function. The callee compiler, will just treat the function as if it conforms to the ABI of **itself**.

Assuming the two compilers use a *similar* ABI, in most cases, no errors will be reported during compile-time or link time or even during runtime. For some compatible compilers like Clang, GCC, and Intel C Compiler on OS X and Linux, no errors *should* result (if there are errors then it's a bug of the compiler). However in real world it is usually difficult to find fully compatible compilers (in most cases their ABIs are *similar* but not exactly the same; such ABI errors will be even harder to track down because your app would appear normal and crashes under some really weird circumstances are encountered during runtime).

Just as Basile said, name mangling for C++ poses an additional difference in ABI, but such differences are more easily caught during compile time as the linker literally can't *find* the symbol of the function, rather than finding a function that is not compatible.

Also, passing structures is another headache in terms of ABI because there are multiple structure-packing ABIs, sometimes even different in "compatible" compilers like GCC/MinGW and MSVC. (See also the `-m[no-]ms-bitfields` option in GCC, which forces GCC to use the MSVC ABI for structures.) I have also seen some cases where passing structures by pointer is [more reliable](https://github.com/libav/libav/blob/master/libavcodec/libopenh264enc.c#L73-L82) than passing structures by value.

Answer (score 4):

The layout of data (e.g. structures etc...), and the call protocol (how are call done at the processor level) are defined in a (processor and operating system specific) document called [Application Binary Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface). If both compilers are following the same ABI (for the same processor and the same operating system) their generated code should be interoperable.

See e.g. the wikipage for [x86 calling conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) and the [x86-64 ABI](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) specification.

[Name mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling), notably for C++, might also be an issue.

Read also [Levine's book on *Linkers and Loaders*](http://www.iecc.com/linkers/)